# Chi-square comparing one reference group with two other groups

Tags: r, chi-squared

If this question has been answered elsewhere, please direct me to the appropriate post. thank you!

Below is an example of part of my data. I am trying to determine if there is a statistically significant difference between the different groups of people regarding other variables, such as plan and region. I am only interested in the categorical data for the analysis but there are numerical variables as well that I have not shown below:

```
plan    region    group
HMO     NE        A
PPO     NE        A
HMO     S         B
Other   NE        B
POS     W         C
HMO     S         C
```

I would like to compare plans and regions of different groups of people using chi-square, where the reference is always A. As in, I would like to compare A to B and A to C. For example, I'd like to see if there is a difference between group A vs B and A vs C with regards to the number of people who live in the NE region.

I would like results like the following (please bear in mind my data actually has thousands of rows so n will not be 1):

```
               group A      group B      group C    p-value
plan (n, %)
    HMO        1, 50%       1, 50%       1, 50%       ?
    PPO        1, 50%       0, 0%        0, 0%        ?
    POS        0, 0%        0, 0%        1, 50%       ?
    Other      0, 0%        1, 50%       0, 0%        ?
```

and the same for region

I don't want to create two data frames to compare the counts separately.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What would your table of counts look like exactly that you would want to tun the chi-square test on? What exactly is your hypothesis?

Comment: @MrFlick I have edited my post. Does this clear things up?

Comment: So what you really want to test is whether product C differs from A significantly more than B does. You don't wan to compare B to A, you want to compare B's difference from A to C's difference from A.

Comment: This seems like a question that would be better addressed to https://stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: If you only want p-values for the rows, it means (or should mean) that you have some statistical hypothesis in mind. It's not clear what sort of hypothesis this might be. Generally an "insurance product" would of necessity be only one type plan, so there would not be any chance of random variation to test.

Comment: Thank you @caleb

Comment: @42 products are not insurance products. I've edited the question to eliminate that confusion.